# How can get the execution hour in Airflow DAG context

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I would like to get the execution hour inside a DAG context. I checked and found that `{{ds}}` provides only the execution date and not time. Is there any way to get the `hour` at which the DAG gets executed on any given day ?

```py
with DAG(dag_id="dag_name", schedule_interval="30 * * * *", max_active_runs=1) as dag:
        features_hourly = KubernetesPodOperator(
        task_id="task-name",
        name="task-name",
        cmds=[
            "python", "-m", "sql_library.scripts.sql_executor",
            "--template", "format",
            "--env-names", "'" + json.dumps(["SCHEMA"]) + "'",
            "--vars", "'" + json.dumps({
                "EXECUTION_DATE": "{{ ds }}", 
                "PREDICTION_HOUR": ??,
                }) + "'",
            "sql_filename.sql",
        ],
        **default_task_params,
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`execution_date` is a `Pendulum.DateTime` object which holds an attribute `hour` ([docs](https://pendulum.eustace.io/docs/#attributes-and-properties)):

```py
{{ execution_date.hour }}
```

You can find examples and more details about the template variables in the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html).

Note that `execution_date` is deprecated since Airflow 2.2. The equivalent is now `{{ dag_run.logical_date }}`.